# Ubuntu files worthless on Windows?

Tags: windows, ntfs, ext4, bookmarks

If my Ubuntu is installed in ext4, will everything I download and write there be worthless if I try to view it on Windows 10?

Is it possible to convert anything without losing it?
Will I be able to copy bookmarks from Windows onto Ubuntu?

Comment: That is more than 1 question. Each of them could be duped to a different existing one, but it is not completely clear what you mean by: *will everything I download and write there be worthless if I try to view it on Windows 10?* - you want to view it on ext4 *from* Windows (on ext4) or use the files on Windows?

Comment: Both. Through converting them somehow if this is possible. But first and foremost I wonder if I can copy a bookmark file from windows chrome onto ubuntu in ext4.

Comment: What do you want to copy? Pictures or programs? Add more detail to your question please.

Comment: Pictures mostly, music. No programs.

Comment: You can always mount the Windows 10 partition and save it directly there from Ubuntu.  Ubuntu will read and write to NTFS, but most apps for Windows anymore will no longer read or write to ext4, well, at least I haven't found any.  So, I used either another server with Samba / NFS, or I just use a shared drive between them both.  One comment on the linked answers states that all files show up in Linux as executable because it is not supported by NTFS, but it shouldn't be a problem unless you are trying to keep permissions, etc.

Comment: So this question wrongly marked as duplicate, as "read from windows" is 9 years old question and doesn't include windows 10. And there are no question how to move bookmarks from firefox browser to chrome. Better to use sync and same browser as writen in my answer.

Comment: So that means Ubuntu can read other files than ext4? Because my ubuntu is in ext4 and it couldn't open my hard drive when plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use browser's sing in to sync, both on windows and ubuntu. Your bookmarks will be synced, also history, logins, and so on.

This way applicable both for Firefox and Chrome but separate for each other.

There are software to access ext4 from windows, so you can copy files to ubuntu. I don't remember application name, but you can easy search for it. Bookmarks are not files, but records in browser profile, so use sync for them instead of copy.

Comment: Thanks. Can I copy files from ubuntu to windows?

Comment: Yes, just find windows partition in "Files - other locations" and click on it to mount.

Comment: Can I mount a hard drive in exFAT in Ubuntu?

Comment: May be you system haven't support for it yet, easy to add: `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

Comment: Thanks! What about MPEG-4 AAC decoder, H.264 (Main Profile) decoder?